# Mercurial .hgignore regex matching a specific filename in a folder and its subfolders

Tags: regex, mercurial, hgignore

My Mercurial folder structure is like this, where "temp" is in the root of the folder.

```
temp
|   1world
|   world
|   world.txt
|           
+---sub1
|       1world
|       world
|       world.txt
|       
+---sub2
+---sub3
|       misc.txt
|       other
|       otherfile.txt
|       
\---sub4
        world
```

I would like to ignore everything in the temp folder and its subfolders, except for files which are named "world" (only "world" and not "1world" or "world.txt" etc.)

Using syntax: regexp in .hgignore, I can match temp > world using `^temp/(?!world$)`, but I'm not able to get the full regex string right (to match world in all temp subfolders as well).

Any guidance will be much appreciated!

**Update**

I managed to get the result I wanted by manually listing each folder as such:

```
^temp/(?!world$|sub1|sub2|sub3|sub4)
^temp/sub1/(?!world$)
^temp/sub2/(?!world$)
^temp/sub3/(?!world$)
^temp/sub4/(?!world$)
```

However, I would much prefer it if I could just match world in all subfolders with a pattern, as it's easy to forget to update .hgignore when things change.

Comment: Could you maybe also put how you're using the regex? There might be some other commands more suitable?

Comment: Hmm, .hgignore is a plain text file, so I just entered the regex there. Not sure if I answered your question..?

Comment: Oh... I was just wondering because there's a page filled with different commands [here](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#patterns).

Answer (score 0):

If you have to list all the folders anyway, you should just put `.` in your `.hgignore`, which means ignore everything, and then `hg add` the `world` files you want.

A `.hgignore` exists only to affect which **unadded** files you see when you do a `hg status` but if you have to add an entry for every file you want not-ignored then you're not seeing the `world` files that you need to add anyway.  So instead of adding another line to your `.hgignore` just `had add path_to_new_folder/world`.

Once a file is added `.hgignore` has no effect on it at all.

So from the start the process would be:

```
echo . > `.hgignore   # create a new hgignore file with just a single got in it
hg add **/world       # add all the files named exactly world
hg commit             # commit those world files
```

Now it's still possible for you to forget to add new `world` files by forgetting to run `hg add **/world` again, but at least that's easier than having to remember to add another exception to your `.hgignore`.